# Spark UI is inaccessible from host for sequenceiq/spark:1.6.0

Tags: apache-spark, docker

I have used given command. I am able to run a spark PI and stand-alone programs, but when I tried to spark UI its not accessible from host. Any help ?

```
docker pull sequenceiq/spark:1.6.0
docker build --rm -t sequenceiq/spark:1.6.0 .
docker run -it -p 8088:8088 -p 8042:8042 -p 4040:4040 -h sandbox sequenceiq/spark:1.6.0 bash
docker run -i -t -v /scratch:/mnt -e 8088 -e 8042 -e 4040  sequenceiq/spark:1.6.0 /bin/bash
docker run -d -h sandbox sequenceiq/spark:1.6.0 -d
#run the spark shell
spark-shell \
--master yarn-client \
--driver-memory 1g \
--executor-memory 1g \
--executor-cores 1

#execute the the following command which should return 1000
scala> sc.parallelize(1 to 1000).count()
```

Spark shell snippet :

```
16/12/08 22:42:27 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@172.17.0.5:43371]
16/12/08 22:42:27 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 43371.
16/12/08 22:42:27 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/12/08 22:42:27 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/12/08 22:42:27 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-61bf4e4d-e0f9-48a9-924f-8971c3d916e7
16/12/08 22:42:27 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 511.5 MB
16/12/08 22:42:28 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/12/08 22:42:28 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
16/12/08 22:42:28 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
16/12/08 22:42:28 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/12/08 22:42:28 INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://172.17.0.5:4040
16/12/08 22:42:28 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting  SPARK_LOCAL_IP to host's ip and then try to access

Comment: I am trying given command. In this case spark context initialization itself fails                                                                                                Command : docker run -i -t -v /scratch:/mnt -e 8088 -e 8042 -e 4040 -e SPARK_LOCAL_IP="10.240.36.174" sequenceiq/spark:1.6.0 /bin/bash

Comment: no need of quotes just  give  --env SPARK_LOCAL_IP=10.240.36.174

Answer (score 0):

Got the Answer, I was running a spark shell with master as Yarn . so this job was visible under resource manager UI.

If I run a spark shell with local as master Spark UI works fine.

Please make sure what is your master and choose your UI

Comment: Comment from : https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-spark/issues/2 matyix commented on Oct 30, 2014

In yarn-cluster mode you should not expect to see the UI, as when you submit a Spark job in a YARN cluster the only dependency is the spark-yarn, which does not contain any of the web stuff.
Check the logs for both (client and cluster) modes and you will see the difference.

You can always track your application by connecting to the resource manager's UI on 8088.

Comment: You can [edit] your posts. No need to comment after yourself.